# Using react-native and styled-components how can I change a child props?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I need to change a color of a `<Text/>` that's inside a TouchableHighlight styled-component. Already tried:

```
const Button = styled.TouchableHighlight`
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    
    Text {
      color: orange;
    }
`;
```

Didn't worked... also this `Text` it's from react-native, not an styled-component component.

Answer (score 1):

create separate style component for `Text`

```
// styled component
const StyledText = styled.Text`
   color: orange;
`;
```

and use `StyledText` instead of `Text` in your code